# playlist order not transfering to iphone

Tags: iphone, itunes, playlists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preserving smart playlist order on iPhone](https://superuser.com/questions/42873/preserving-smart-playlist-order-on-iphone)

I have smart playlist that I have manually ordered in iTunes (V9.0) and then transferred the playlist to my iPhone (3G running 3.1) by syncing via iTunes. However the order does not transfer. I have rightclicked the playlist and selected "Copy to Play Order" but this does not seem to do anything. I don't think this was happening a few weeks ago before I updated to Snow Leopard and iPhone 3.1

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone, it should be a bug from iTunes.

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/42873/preserving-smart-playlist-order-on-iphone) and [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2154509&tstart=0).